# how to play specific song BackgroundAudioPlayer windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Hi i'm trying to play a specifc song for example if i have a list with 100 songs i want to play the song   #20

to do this i use the following code

```
private void playSong(int n)
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["currentSong"] = n;

    if (BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState == PlayState.Playing)
    {

        BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Close();

        BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play();

    }
    else
        BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play();
}
```

And then in my AudioPlayer.cs i get the song

```
//get the song
currentSong = (int)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["currentSong"];
```

It works fine but it takes too much time to load the song.

so please is there any other way to do this?

thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't really take long to load it if you know the location and file name of the song. Show the code snippet that gets the song by the index.